# Foreach loops over Eigen matrices?

Tags: c++11, foreach, eigen

Is it possible to use the foreach syntax of C++11 with Eigen matrices? For instance, if I wanted to compute the sum of a matrix (I know there's a builtin function for this, I just wanted a simple example) I'd like to do something like

```
Matrix2d a;
a << 1, 2,
     3, 4;
double sum = 0.0;
for(double d : a) {
  sum += d;
}
```

However Eigen doesn't seem to allow it. Is there a more natural way to do a foreach loop over elements of an Eigen matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Range-based for loops need the methods `.begin()` and `.end()` to be implemented on that type, which they are not for Eigen matrices. However, as a pointer is also a valid random access iterator in C++, the methods `.data()` and `.data() + .size()` can be used for the begin and end functions for any of the STL algorithms.

Comment: `begin()` and `end()` can be implemented as members, or as free functions (which are found using ADL).

Comment: This approach does not take the Matrix stride into account: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01DirectWriteAccessors_01_4.html#ab6af285d1c2135599fc10505f8bc4473. This may lead to some unwanted side effects like floating point operations with uninitialized values, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it does not take into account stride and that could be dangerous when using a base type. I've just done some reading and it seems from v3.4 (not yet stable), Eigen will support iterators - https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html

Answer (score 3):

For your particular case, it's more useful to obtain start and end iterators yourself, and pass both iterators to a standard algorithm:

```
auto const sum = std::accumulate(a.data(), a.data()+a.size(), 0.0);
```

If you have another function that really needs range-based `for`, you need to provide implementations of `begin()` and `end()` in the same namespace as the type (for argument-dependent lookup).  I'll use C++14 here, to save typing:

```
namespace Eigen
{
    auto begin(Matrix2d& m) { return m.data(); }
    auto end(Matrix2d& m) { return m.data()+m.size(); }
    auto begin(Matrix2d const& m) { return m.data(); }
    auto end(Matrix2d const& m) { return m.data()+m.size(); }
}
```

Comment: Don’t range-based `for` loops require unqualified `begin(a)`/`end(a)`? So wouldn’t those need to be in the global namespace or in the `Eigen` namespace (to be found by ADL)?

Comment: Yes @Ben, I think you're right (and non-argument-dependent lookup is not performed).

Comment: Any idea why Eigen doesn’t provide this?

Comment: Probably just because no-one ever wrote it.  Perhaps the project would welcome a suitable patch?  Or at least a bug report.

Comment: This approach does not take the Matrix stride into account: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01DirectWriteAccessors_01_4.html#ab6af285d1c2135599fc10505f8bc4473.

Comment: Thanks for that @VirtualVDX - I don't know the Eigen library well, so I was ignorant of its strides.  It seems that a small iterator class is necessary (but the principle is sound).  Would you care to expand with a worked example?

Answer (score 2):

STL style iterator support has been added to Eigen in version 3.4.

See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html

For OP's question, you can do the following:

```
Matrix2d A;
A << 1, 2,
     3, 4;
double sum = 0.0;
for(auto x : A.reshaped())
 sum += x;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, only from version 3.3.9, which is not considered stable at the moment
(currently, I'm depending on the version 3.3.7)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to the data array of the matrix can be obtained using the member function `.data()`.

The size of the data array can also be obtained using the member function `.size()`.

Using these two, we now have the pointers to the first element and end of the array as `a.data()` and `a.data()+a.size()`.

Also, we know that an `std::vector` can be initialized using iterators (or array pointers in our case).

Thus, we can obtain a vector of doubles that wraps the matrix elements with `std::vector<double>(a.data(), a.data()+a.size())`.

This vector can be used with the range-based for loop syntax that is included in your code snippet as:

```
  Matrix2d a;
  a << 1, 2,
       3, 4;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(double d : std::vector<double>(a.data(), a.data()+a.size())) {
      sum += d;
  }
```

Comment: This would perform a copy of the matrix, not iterate over the matrix itself, probably not something the asker wants to do.